# How to set Text at middle position in `fieldset legend `

Tags: html, css, legend, fieldset

How to set Legend text in middle of border in `field set`?

I have tried this html code:

```
<fieldset>
    <legend align="center"> 
              This is text appear at center of border
    </legend>
</fieldset>
```

I also tried with `margin-left: 100px` but I don't want to use margin-left because of design limitations.

Comment: it work in  [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4vnSN/2/)

Comment: It works in both manner: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4vnSN/3/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**CSS** is your friend here

```
legend {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: thats easy you can add border to it. Paste your existing css for that in your question

Comment: where to add border whether to `legend` or `fieldset`

Comment: if you add border to fieldset it will then border around all area which contains your fields that follow. If you add border to only legend then it will, as expected, add border only to your legend's area

Answer (score 0):

try to give the "legend element" a width with percentage like 10%.
then give it margin-left:45% ((100-10)/2)

```
legend {
width: 10%;
text-align: center;
margin-left:45%;
```

}

it will be in the center between the border